# cloneNode() seems broken in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, dom

While developing code to dynamically modify a table I found that IE10 and FireFox (v38) don't seem to work the same way.

I have a table with some check boxes in it. I also have a button that triggers a javascript to manipulate the table rows dynamically.

The javascript removes the rows and then adds them back.

I click on one or both checkboxes and then press the button.

In IE, the checkboxes are restored to their original settings, while in FireFox they keep their new settings.

I would like them to keep their new settings and I would like to be able to keep the code browser-independent.

How should I copy the current state of the table rows?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>RemoveAppend.html</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function testSort() {
                var rows = [];
                var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                var trows = table.rows;
                var rowslength = table.rows.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < rowslength; i++) {
                    // We'll need to clone these since the references
                    // will be removed when we empty the table.
                    rows.push(table.rows[i].cloneNode(true));
                }
                while (table.firstChild) {
                    table.removeChild(table.firstChild);
                }

                //for (var i = rowslength - 1; i >= 0; i=i-1) 
                for (var i = 0; i < rowslength; i++) {
                        table.appendChild(rows[i]);
                }
                return;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="foo.action" method="post" name="form1" >
            <table id="myTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap">Column header</th>
                    <th align="left">Data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="pyjamas">
                <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="dd_19675" id="dd_19675" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="d_19675" id="d_19675" />
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap">
                    <label for="dd_19675" style="width:100%;display:block">First</label>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="">
                <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="dd_19676" id="dd_19676" checked="checked" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="d_19676" id="d_19676" checked="checked" />
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap">
                    <label for="dd_19676" style="width:100%;display:block">Second</label>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="button" value="Sort" onclick="testSort()" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code is just html and javascript, so it is easy to try in a browser.

Note: Don't be mislead by the references to sorting in the code. I have removed the sorting from the code before posting because it wasn't relevant to my question.

**Update:**

I have tested the code on IE11 and it works like FireFox, so the problem seems specific to IE10.

**Update 2:**

Seems I made a mistake when simplifying the code. My example missed the actual problem.

The actual problem is that when I copy the nodes, the posted value for the checkboxes changes from the default `on` to nothing. This only happens in IE10, not IE11 or FireFox.

Comment: `cloneNode` is compatible with all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/du66at3f/1/ - seems fine in IE11

Comment: I am using IE10 (question updated).

Comment: Why do you need to use `cloneNode`? What do you mean the references will be removed? If you're holding references in your array, you can reuse them later (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild ). I tried your code without the `cloneNode` and it works just fine - is there something else in your real code that's causing an issue?

Comment: I did nothing but add borders to the code and I see nothing happening. What should I expect? Did I copy it wrong? http://plnkr.co/edit/sViq0Xy9ke82GiVFrYXN?p=preview Btw, when is `trows` used?

Comment: Sorry, I see they are created then removed immediately...er ok. Anyways where is `trows` used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points here:

- You don't need to remove the rows - if you re-sort them and just append them, they'll be moved
- Even if you do remove them, you don't need to clone them if you have a reference in your rows array - once you hold any reference, the DOM node won't be deleted (see [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild))
- In your example you're removing the `thead` and `tbody`, not sure if that was deliberate

I've simplified your code a bit here, removing `cloneNode`, not removing the rows from the `table` at all, and targeting the `tbody` instead of the `table`. To illustrate, I reverse the rows each time you click:

```js
function testSort() {
  var rows = [];
  var tbody = document.getElementById("data");
  var rowslength = tbody.rows.length;
  
  // reversing rows to illustrate
  for (var i = 0; i < rowslength; i++) {
    rows.unshift(tbody.rows[i]);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < rowslength; i++) {
    tbody.appendChild(rows[i]);
  }
  return;
}
```

```html
<form action="foo.action" method="post" name="form1">
  <table id="myTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th align="left" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap">Column header</th>
        <th align="left">Data</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">
      <tr class="pyjamas">
        <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
          <input type="checkbox" name="dd_19675" id="dd_19675" />
          <input type="hidden" name="d_19675" id="d_19675" />
        </td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap">
          <label for="dd_19675" style="width:100%;display:block">First</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="">
        <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
          <input type="checkbox" name="dd_19676" id="dd_19676" checked="checked" />
          <input type="hidden" name="d_19676" id="d_19676" checked="checked" />
        </td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap">
          <label for="dd_19676" style="width:100%;display:block">Second</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="button" value="Sort" onclick="testSort()" />
</form>
```

Comment: It was not my intention to remove `thead` and `tbody` but rather the rows in `tbody`. Therefore my example doesn't show my actual problem. Your answer helped so I could get back on track and find the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

This answer describes how I solved the actual problem (as described in Update 2  of the question).

In the servlet I changed the code so that I no longer care what value a checkbox has. All information I need is in the name. The mere presence of the key indicates that the checkbox is checked:

```
Enumeration<String> parameters = request.getParameterNames();
while (parameters.hasMoreElements()) {
    String pName = (String) parameters.nextElement();
    if (pName.startsWith("dd_")) {
        // Checked checkbox! (I let all checkbox names start with dd_ on this page)
```

I also added a fat comment blaming IE10.